# Execute one specific phpUnit test with zend 1.12

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I'm using Zend 1.12 and I would like to execute only one specific test from my terminal

I tried

```
phpunit --filter testRequestCreation SynchroRequestTest application/Synchro/Request
```

but it returns an error

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
phpunit --filter 'TempGetDatasetTest::testInsertDatabase$'
```